# What's the difference between -p tcp and -m tcp in iptables?

Tags: firewall, iptables

I just noticed an entry in /etc/sysconfig/iptables along the lines of `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 138 -j DROP`

I am not so sure why there has to be two switches here for matching protocol TCP, that is, `-p tcp` and `-m tcp`. Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

> **-p** The protocol of the rule or of the packet to check.
>
> The specified protocol can be one of tcp, udp, icmp, or all, or it can
>   be a numeric value, representing one of these protocols or a different
>   one. A protocol name from /etc/protocols is also allowed. A "!"
>   argument before the protocol inverts the test. The number zero is
>   equivalent to all. Protocol all will match with all protocols and is
>   taken as default when this option is omitted.
>
> **-m** Specifies a match to use, that is, an extension module that tests for a specific property.
>
> The set of matches make up the condition under which a target is
>   invoked. Matches are evaluated first to last as specified on the
>   command line and work in short-circuit fashion, i.e. if one extension
>   yields false, evaluation will stop.

**Added info**

**-m** Also matches packets of the specified protocol name. If '!' precedes the protocol name, this matches all packets that are not of the specified protocol. Valid protocol names are icmp, udp, tcp... A list of all the valid protocols could be found in the file /etc/protocols. So I think it would be safe to omitt the `-m`

<sup>Source:[IPtables ManPage](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know now that `-p tcp` is used to check for tcp packets, but what about `-m tcp` ? Is it used to check some TCP extension module?

Comment: And also, I see in some place that `-m tcp` is omitted... can it always be omitted?

Comment: See added info in the answer.